# Welch function python-matlab equivalence

Tags: python, matlab, scipy

I'm trying to get the same results using the pwelch function from matlab and the welch function from scipy in python.

To do so, I tried to know which parameters in matlab correspond to which parameter in python and I write my code like this:

In Matlab:

```
    [pxx,f]=pwelch(data,1000,500,1024,fs,'onesided')
```

In python:

```
    f, pxx = scipy.signal.welch(data, fs=fs, nperseg=1000, noverlap=500, nfft=1024, return_onesided=True)
```

In the end, I don't get the same results at all, any suggestions ??

Thanks !

Comment: Show us the plots maybe it would help.

Comment: For one thing, MATLAB's version uses a hamming window while scipy uses a hanning window.

Answer (score 0):

If your input array is a matrix of columnwise independent time series, make sure that Python and MATLAB have performed the same ordering of the values, ie. row-wise and columnwise.